# How to multiply a 2 user inputs with two numbers then add them in assembly 8086 processor?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, multiplication

I wish to have 2 user inputs. For example 8 and 3. Then I would to multiply them with the variable f1 and f2 so 8 x f1 and 3 x f2. Then I would like to add them so (8 x f1) + (3 x f2). I do not know how to multiply the user input with the variable and finally adding them together

```
 ;TITLE Multiply input with number then add them

.model small
.stack 100
.data
   
f1 DB 10
f2 DB 20

msg1 DB 13,10,"First input = $" ;--ask user to input 1 digit. Example = 8
msg2 DB 13,10,"Second input = $" ;--ask user to input 1 digit. Example = 3
msg3 DB 13,10,"Product = $" ;--multiply the first and second input with f1 and f2. So 8x10 and 3x20
msg4 DB 13,10,"Addition = $" ;--Add those numbers that have been multiplied to 80 + 60 = 140


q1 DB ? ;user inputs
q2 DB ?



.code
main proc 
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax


mov ah,09h
lea dx, msg1
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov q1,al

;--multiplication of 1st user input with f1 here but idk how


mov ah,09h
lea dx, msg2
int 21h


mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov q2,al

;--multiplication of 2nd user input with f2 here but idk how


mov ah,09h
lea dx, msg4
int 21h

;--Addition of those 2 multiplied numbers here

mov ah, 4Ch 
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul) for the `mul` instruction?

Answer (score 1):

In the 8086 processor, you can choose between the *byte-sized* multiplication (result in `AX`) and the *word-sized* multiplication (result in `DX:AX`). Because your numbers are small you should choose:

#### the byte-sized multiplication.

The `AL` register gets multiplied by the byte-sized operand that you specify in the `mul` instruction. The product will get stored in the `AX` register.

```
mov al, q1
mul f1       ; -> AX is product
```

Here you need to store the product somewhere safe, because the second multiplication will mandatory have to use that same `AX` register!

Addition of both products should not be too difficult...

In case you need to display the outcome of the calculation on the screen, you can read [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos).